# How to fit a table inside a jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I am using JQuery UI tabs in a very simple way.

$( "#top-level" ).tabs(  );

When I add a wide table to the content...  the page scrolls horizontally
but the tab does not.

So I thought to scroll the table inside the tab...  the only answer I can find is to set the table to a fixed size.   Not a great answer.

What I really want is for the tab content to recognize the width of the table.

I created a stripped down example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table inside tab</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="/js/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/jquery-ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/libs/jquery-ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css"></link> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/libs/jquery-ui-lightness/jquery-ui.structure.min.css"></link> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/libs/jquery-ui-lightness/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"></link>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#top-level" ).tabs(  );  //{ heightStyle: "fill" }
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .tab_content {
        }
        .top-div {

        }
        table {

        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="top-level" class="top-div">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#exec">Summary</a></li>
     </ul>


     <div id="exec" class="tab_content">
        <table id="myTable" border="1"> 
            <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" id="measure">Measurement</th> 
                <th rowspan="2" id="cellname">Cell Name</th> 
                <th colspan="5">-40&deg; C</th>
                <th colspan="5">27&deg; C</th>
                <th colspan="5">150&deg; C</th>
                <th rowspan="2" id="exception">Exceptions</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <th>Cp</th> 
                <th>Cpk</th> 
                <th>Min</th> 
                <th>Max</th> 
                <th>Pass</th> 
                <th>Cp</th> 
                <th>Cpk</th> 
                <th>Min</th> 
                <th>Max</th> 
                <th>Pass</th> 
                <th>Cp</th> 
                <th>Cpk</th> 
                <th>Min</th> 
                <th>Max</th> 
                <th>Pass</th> 
            </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 

            <tr>
                <td>FNcycleShutdown</td>
                <td>fb_top</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="bad_value">FALSE</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="bad_value">FALSE</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>TRUE</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>VaccuracyVDDGDat16at0mA</td>
                <td>VDD3P3_LDO_top</td>
                <td class="bad_value">1.9</td>
                <td class="bad_value">1.4</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PhaseMargin</td>
                <td>VDD3P3_LDO_top</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="bad_value">3.7</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody> 
            </table> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to add a rule in css for the tab, in this case would be like:

```
#exec
{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Here an example:
http://codepen.io/wallek876/pen/eNOwvy

Comment: thanks for the input.  I have fiddled with those overflow settings to death!  None of them prevents the horizontal scroll bar from disappearing off the bottom of the page if the table gets longer than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the table with BootStrap CSS class `table-responsive`. It will fit inside `tab-content` DIV

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of that hook.  Always glad to have another tool.   But it is sooo hard to get the content to fill the viewport and NOT have the scroll bar drop out of visibility.  Maybe I'm a perfectionist.  But I hate having to answer that question a thousand times... "where did the scrollbar go?"   I think it is not just jquery ui, but also the layout engine in chrome.